# For which angles $a$ is $\sin^4 a - \cos^4 a > \sin^2 a - \cos^2 a$?

Tags: trigonometry, self-learning

My questions

1. For which angles $a$ is $\sin^4 a - \cos^4 a > \sin^2 a - \cos^2 a$?
2. For which angles $a$ is $\sin^4 a - \cos^4 a \ge \sin^2 a - \cos^2 a$?

I understand that the two sides will be equal at $90$ degrees and at $45$ degrees. And I understand that between $45$ and $90$ degrees the first inequality is valid. Below $45$ degrees it isn't.  Is this correct?
Thanks.

Comment: do you mean $\sin(4\alpha) $ or $\sin^4 \alpha $ ?

Comment: I mean $\sin^4\alpha$

Comment: There is no such angle $a.$

Answer (score 5):

Hints:

$$\sin^2\alpha+\cos^2\alpha=1.$$

Comment: Awww, that was my answer (pout, pout).

Answer (score 1):

For the first case, there is no such $\alpha$ that suffices the inequality.

For the second case, it suffices for all $\alpha$.

This is proven when you use $sin^2 + cos^2 = 1$ to change both sides and see that both sides are actually saying the same thing.